# Handling ConstraintviolationException in JPA

Tags: java, jpa, spring-boot

My problem is very usual but i can't seem to find any solution. I have searched a lot but didn't find anything

**Situation:**

tried to insert a row which caused foreign key violation that caused my transaction to rollback.
No matter what exception i handle it always throws 500 from my rest endpoint which is not acceptable at all

**Question:**
How to handle this gracefully. Below is my code which is not working

```
@Transactional(dontRollbackOn={InvalidModelException.class,PersistenceException.class,ConstraintViolationException.class,MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException.class})
    @Override   
    public PointAudit createPointAudit(PointAudit pointAudit) throws EmptyModelException, InvalidModelException {
        if(pointAudit != null) {
            try {
                this.entityManager.persist(pointAudit);
                this.entityManager.flush();
            }

            catch(RollbackException x) {
                LOGGER.error(x.getMessage(), x);
            }
            catch(PersistenceException x) {
                if(x.getCause() instanceof ConstraintViolationException) {
                    if(x.getCause().getCause() instanceof MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException)
                    {
                        MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException e = (MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException)x.getCause().getCause();
                        if(e.getMessage().contains("USER_ID")) {
                            throw new InvalidModelException("Invalid user is provided");
                        }
                        else {
                            if(e.getMessage().contains("STATUS")) {
                                throw new InvalidModelException("Invalid status is provided");
                            }
                            else {
                                if(e.getMessage().contains("CHANNEL")) {
                                    throw new InvalidModelException("Invalid channel is provided");
                                }
                                else {
                                    if(e.getMessage().contains("ACTION")) {
                                        throw new InvalidModelException("Invalid action is provided");
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
                else {
                    while( !(x.getCause() instanceof RollbackException) || x.getCause() == null) {
                        LOGGER.error(x.getMessage(), x);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            throw new EmptyModelException("Point Audit is empty");
        }
        return pointAudit;
    }
```

If any further code is required please let me know

Comment: WHat do you mean by "handle"? Return the client something else than `http-500` with stacktrace?

Comment: Normally i can get the excat cause of the error, I want to respond Http-500 with correct error message

Comment: You are catching and swallowing the exceptions. Spring does't see it, tries to commit after the method completes, it cannot and hence an error. Never catch and swallow exceptions it will break proper tx management. Next to that you tell it to ignore certain exceptions for rollback and thus will commit but how can a constraintvoilation lead to a proper commit?

Comment: i tried to catch exception in order to understand if it is a known case, not otherwise. The other part where i tried to skip some exceptions, to be frank those were to see if that can make me handle the exceptions myself.